# Make LaTeX table caption same width as table?

Tags: latex, width, caption

It looks bad in my paper if a caption is wider than the table underneath it. How can I make them both align?

Right now my code looks like:

```
\begin{table}[th!]
\caption{Reference temperature blah blah}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: can you show us what you use now?

Comment: There is a special site for TeX/LaTeX questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your table plus caption inside a minipage.  The caption will wrap. This is also a great way to have proper footnotes for tables.

Comment: I think I might have already tried that... how do I get the minipage to the table width?

Comment: Search in this page for *Side-by-side tables* (shows an example of specifying minipage width): http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/latex/

Answer (score 41):

Actually there is a more legal way to do this using captions package option `width`.

For global effect

```
\usepackage[width=.75\textwidth]{caption}
```

For local effect only in current environment:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{width=.75\textwidth}
```

More info in caption package doc:

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption?lang=en

http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf (direct link to PDF subject to change)

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that the caption text is justified, so that the text is flush with the left and right boundaries of the caption?

Comment: Using this seems to alter alignment.

Answer (score 14):

if you know or find out the width of the table, let's say 5cm -

- if you're using a KOMA-Script class:

  \setcapwidth[c]{5cm}
- if you're using the caption package:

  \captionsetup{width=5cm}

Both may be applied inside the table environment.

An automatically calculating solution is more complicated, but could be done using the [\settowidth](http://texblog.net/help/latex/ltx-90.html) command.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Although why isn't this on tex.stackexchange?

Comment: If I use `\captionsetup{width=5cm}`, the alignment is shifted.

Answer (score 14):

I've had success by putting my caption in a parbox:

```
\parbox{5cm}{\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...}}
```

Comment: use \parbox{\textwidth}{\caption{..}} to get rid of hard coded numbers

Answer (score 5):

in caption package guide:

> Only fixed widths are supported here; if you are looking for a way to
>   limit the width of the caption to the width of the figure or table,
>   please take a look at the **floatrow**[8] or **threeparttable**[22] package.

Comment: As Hadi recommends, I used the **threeparttable** package to have a table caption as wide as the table. I put the table caption between *\begin{threeparttable}* and *\end{threeparttable}*.